# View ajax not working with bueditor

Tags: views, ajax

I am using drupal 7 and views. The ajax functionality is not working if I enable bueditor for a textarea. I changed the form element by a custom module like this below:

```
$form['description']['#type'] = 'text_format';
$form['description']['#format'] = 'full_html';
```

now problem is that if I remove the type and format, the bueditor is not showing that is good and also the form which I build using drupal views it is working with ajax.

But If i add these 2 lines mentioned above, the bueeditor is appearing but ajax is not working. Submitting to a page instead of ajax.

What is the problem there?

I got some more points. As I checked the ajax is working with the bueditor but not clicking on the submit button, its working when I click on the first element of the bueditor(a input tag for Italic). I think the ajax event is bind with the first element of input button. Really fustrated

Thanks in advance.